# Intellij IDEA 13: how do I disable refactor comments and strings?

Tags: intellij-idea

```
public class KV<K, V> {
    public K key;
    public V value;
    public KV(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    } 
}
```

I am trying to refactor the class variable `value`, which happens in place. That means no dialog pops up; I press enter and it tries to refactor across the entire project, including comments and what not, including:

```
<%--<link href="<c:url value="../core/core.css" />" />--%>
```

in a .jsp file. That is way too "clever" to try to refactor **comments** that match across the entire project. This often causes lots of bug risk, and refactoring in a Java environment is no longer safe.

The same thing was occurring in Intellij 12. Seriously, I don't need Intellij to recommend anything that is considered unsafe, or when it is not sure it is the same thing!

I can exclude the refactorings but I don't have time to evaluate five "suggestions" every time. It just raises the chance of human error: most of the time I just press enter, and woops things are refactored.

Refactoring is also a major issue in a Java environment when it sometimes tries to replace things in .js files. Seriously, this has to stop.

Without the popup dialog, I can't untick "search strings". Even if that was ticked, Intellij should *never* include the suggestions by default, especially when it is outside the current file. It can recommend to refactor them as well, but they should be excluded by default. That is, it should be an opt-in feature, rather than by default destroying everything.

This is a serious user experience problem with more recent so called "smart" Intellij refactoring. When refactoring JS files, I don't want to search Java files for comments or strings! Period! And vice versa!

Safety comes first! Developers that know what they are doing will search for strings themselves if needed. In a dynamic language environment it makes Intellij impossible to use, because frequently, and without any clear pattern, sometimes refactorings go through, sometimes it changes things across the project and what not.

There should be an option that says, "refactor only relative to this file or when 100% inferred!", especially for dynamic languages! For static languages it shouldn't even attempt to look for comments and strings outside the file.

I didn't mean to put it out in public, but I have raised this issue over 2 years ago in the bugtracker, but nobody paid any attention.

**EDIT**

For those of you that think that I might be going to far, I just tried this out:

With this class:

```
public class KV<K, V> {
    public K key;
    public V val;
    public KV(K key, V val) {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

And adding this to **any** Java class, for instance:

```
public class CoreConfig {
    String abc = "kv.val";
    String def = "somethingElse.val";
}
```

When refactoring `KV.val` as before, I get the following recommendations, an ENTER from disaster and something I have to evaluate and exclude one at a time. It takes effort and is just annoying and risky. It's like someone yelling out, STOP! And then ooh, nothing after a minute, frustration and a 1000 long word essay ( this ).

[image]

Seriously, is there a way to disable this kind of risky behaviour!? And is there any reason why this is on by default??

**EDIT 20200706**

Shit continues in 2020:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245370

Comment: Intellij is full of things forced upon me. If android supported other editors, I'd switch in a heartbeat. I find myself fighting the editor, instead of spending time coding. I spend time here trying to find a way to turn things off. Most of the times, they don't recommend solutions. Most the time they are saying... "WHY DO YOU HATE THIS FEATURE?"

Comment: At the very least this feature should have a minimum length limit - like if I'm refactoring a variable with a common 3-letter name, it makes zero sense to search and replace that in strings and comments _by default_. That 3-letter sequence is overwhelmingly likely to exist in a random string if it's a large project. Ugh.

Comment: It's now plain and simply broken. It used to be the one IDE that made sense. Not being able to turn off this terrible default behavior makes IntelliJ such a terrible tool to use, I've unknowingly created terrible seemingly unrelated bugs by simply renaming variables like IntelliJ has tought me to over years... I keep forgetting that I can't trust its refactoring at all anymore -.-

Comment: Today, it changed a Spring MVC POST mapping's path because I moved the class to a different package (!!!!!!!)

Comment: Yes, this is one of the worst feature of intellij. If I want to rename a class I can end up breaking the whole project where that class name happens to appear in strings. So if you rename the class `User` to `MyUser` it will rename everything including config files, labels, urls, paths in rest calls mapping...

Comment: Yes, a huge reason to why i am constantly looking for new editors. that and aweful window management.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

When you press `Shift + F6 (Refactor Rename)` twice, it opens the dialog and you can disable "Search in comments and strings"

Comment: To be clear that is activating the shortcut for "Refactor Rename" TWICE.  It may be a different combination depending upon your keymapping.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that you can disable the inplace refactor as well, although it is nice, because that always feels like the safe one. The main point of my post was to highlight that the search for comments and strings should be turned off globally. It makes no sense that it tries to alter a value in a variable in a another class. It is not smart. There is a problem when intelligence or AI assumes that by increasing the likelyhood for being correct, it somehow is allowed to have a margin of error. I want strict java refactorings, that should include XML files unless the entire package name exist

Comment: But since it remembers the settings, I see no problem with it. You can use that full text refactoring or not, depending on what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, the checkbox seems to reappear now and then. Does anyone know of a setting that will turn this off permanently? As has been mentioned before IntelliJ is too "smart" for its own good here...

Comment: @Meo it doesn't respect that everywhere. Nowadays the inline, incode text refactoring in javascript is modifying values and comments in code not even in the  function.

Comment: This does not work in javascript at least. See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245370

Answer (score 7):

> And is there any reason why this is on by default??

Yes, there is. People tend to use way too many DSLs, templates and language injections these days. In plain old Java all these things mainly exist as Strings. Reflection API also represents method/class name as a String. It is not possible for any IDE to support and recognize them all, so it does it's best to provide you with a safety net against possible refactoring mistakes. If you have an excellent unit test coverage, though, then you're probably safe here.

As for comments, they often contain code samples. These code chunks become obsolete quickly during renamings, so it's helpful when IDE reminds you about their existence.

This check, of course, results in false positives sometimes. However, if you're giving your variables descriptive self-explanatory names (I mean not "var" or "val"), this is unlikely to happen. So, IDE is pushing you towards a better code style in some way.

If you're still not convinced, then follow an advice by @Meo and disable the search in strings and comments.

Comment: Yeah, it is a good suggestion. But as I commented on his, there is a problem when intelligence or AI assumes that by increasing the likelyhood for being correct, it somehow is allowed to have a margin of error. I want strict java refactorings, that should include XML files unless the entire package name exist, and even then, I want to be notified. The refactor results should not list comments and strings first and should exclude by default. It has become less user friendly, and requires my focus which forces me to lean forward and strains my eyes.

Comment: It is like trying to take down a crammed phone number. Can you repeat this number: 392314213343234295423442 ? For me it is the same kind of effort, and surely for many others. I hope the Intellij guys picks up and gives us the option to turn this off.

Comment: "If you have an excellent unit test coverage, though, then you're probably safe here" - that is not an excuse to provide us with an IDEA that treats Java as a dynamic language. If I wanted a dynamic language I would code in Groovy. "If you're giving your variables descriptive self-explanatory names (I mean not "var" or "val")" - The risk of collision still exists though. Just give us a "Strict" Java mode/option, like Eclipse and Intellij used to offer.

Comment: Then you must really hate(as I do) how the in-editor unused declaration inspection works, it actually does not work if the name of the field or method(or property name in case of property accessors) is contained anywhere in 10 different files... and unlike the rename, it is actually not possible to reconfigure - [IDEA-117906](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117906)

Comment: One misclick and I'll erase Symfony's framework. We should be able to 'exclude by default'.

Comment: Still should be able to control the behavior myself if I wish and not have someone else's standards/historical reasoning forced upon me.

Comment: Just ran into this as well. Absolutely dangerous default to have and I've made the mistake of renaming things like 'value' a couple of times and not noticing right away the epic damage that can do to a project.

Comment: IntelliJ just wanted to replace "entity" with "instance" in my GPL 3 license. Very helpful, thanks a lot.

Comment: It's done worse things. It once polluted a huge crawling job with invalid data because it refactored the HTTP headers in a Map by changing a key to something else. It's a terrible feature and it should be off by default.

Comment: You fail to answer the question, it's more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Issue still exists in 2020 javascript environment at least: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245370